# PHP script works on localhost, but doesn't works on hosting

Tags: php

I have a strange problem. I have a PHP script (witj js, ajax and etc) and it works on localhost very well. But on hosting in internet this script doesn't works. Script is below:

```
     $value = $_POST['web_url'];
        $tag = get_meta_tags("http://".$value);

        if(count($tag['keywords']) == 0)
        {
            echo "<div id='no_keywords'>No keywrds:</div>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div id='title'>My keywords:</div>";
            echo "<br/>";
            print_r($tag['keywords']);
        }
```

For example, in localhost, when I enter: bbc.com - I get all list of keywords(ELSE construction works), but on hosting when I enter bbe.com - I get that 'there are no keywords'(IF construction works always)...Very strange...I don't understand why? Have you got any ideas? ((

Comment: In your question, you say you enter `bbc.com` on localhost but `bbe.com` on remote host; typo in the question, or actual error? Also, please post the code for `get_meta_tags()` so we can see how the remote website is loaded.

Comment: What is your host? SELinux on RH-Family of Linux typically blocks apache httpd from connecting to internet.

Comment: My host is 000webhost...and I can't open any url's...

Answer (score 2):

Your Host server doesnt allow opening URLs:
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: +1 for the most likely answer by far. This is a very common restriction that hosting companies put on PHP for security reasons. If they've turned it off and won't turn it on, you'll have to rewrite your code completely, or switch hosts.

Comment: I can't find, where to allow open URL on hosting panel. Or where can I do it?

Comment: For my testing site I used 000webhost - it's a free hosting with domain. What can you advise me? To use paid hosting?

Comment: Try phpinfo() in your php file and check allow_url_fopen

Comment: If your free hosting server doent allow it then there s no way you can turn it on

Comment: Please, advice me a free hosting with sub domain 3 level, it's not important, where I can place my site and where I can open links.